# Why does List function call return runtime error in Scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

Getting an error for my binary search tree that I created in scheme.

```
$gosh main.sc
*** ERROR: list required, but got 5
Stack Trace:
_______________________________________
```

This is my code. I think the error has to do with how I am calling the functions, but I am not sure what exactly is wrong. I am calling the insert function with the two required parameters: tree, and a value of 5.

```
(define (member? t v)
    (cond 
        ((null? t)
            #f
        )
        ((< node (car t))
            (member? (cadr t) v))
        ((> node (car t))
            (member? (caddr t) v))
        (else
            #t
        )
    )
)

(define (insert t v)
    (cond
        ((null? t)
            (list v '() '())
        )
        ((< v (car t))
            (list (car t) (insert (cadr t) v) (caddr t))
        )
        ((>= v (car t)) 
                (list (car t) (cadr t) (insert (caddr t) v))
        )
        (else
            t
        )
    )
)


(define (fold func val lst)
  (if (null? lst) val (fold func (func val (car lst)) (cdr lst))))

(define (build lst)
  (fold (lambda (t v) (insert t v)) '() lst))

(define t (list 10 '() '()))
(insert t 5)

display  (member t 5)

display t
```

Comment: Can't reproduce in a more mature implementation  It's possible that your interpreter chokes on the syntax errors at the end. (Gauche isn't even version 1.0 yet, so bugs should not be surprising.)

Answer (score 1):

You care calling `(member t 5)` which is the same as `(member '(10 '() '()) 5)`. Now `member` is not the same as your defined `member?` since it has a different name. `member` is the core library that looks like this:

```
(define (member obj lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) #f)
        ((equal? obj (car lst)) lst)
        (else (member obj (cdr lst)))))
```

Your `member?` has the two parameters swapped so when you miswrote the name and used the report version `member` `5` is not null, then it will do `(car 5)` and that will fail miserably. The error message that `5` is not of the required type `list` is pretty decent. It might spell the beans that it was `member` that failed though.

Another thing. If you replace the call to `member` with a call to `member?` you hit more problems. You use a variable `node` that is not defined anywhere.

The indentation and placing of parentheses is not goo lisp style. Your code should be written like this:

```
;; node doesn't exist in OPs code, but my implementation doesn't like member? without it
(define node 5)

;; possible typo by using the variable node ?
(define (member? t v)
  (cond
    ((null? t)
     #f)
    ((< node (car t))
     (member? (cadr t) v))
    ((> node (car t))
     (member? (caddr t) v))
    (else
     #t)))

(define (insert t v)
  (cond
    ((null? t)
     (list v '() '()))
    ((< v (car t))
     (list (car t) (insert (cadr t) v) (caddr t)))
    ((>= v (car t))
     (list (car t) (cadr t) (insert (caddr t) v)))
    (else 
     t)))


(define (fold func val lst)
  (if (null? lst) val (fold func (func val (car lst)) (cdr lst))))

(define (build lst)
  (fold (lambda (t v) (insert t v)) '() lst))

(define t (list 10 '() '()))
(insert t 5)

;; NB doesn't call a procedure, just evaluates it. 
display
;; Here the arguments are the wrong order and you don't use memeber?
(member t 5)
;; NB doesn't call a procedure, just evaluates it. 
display
t
```